# How to test a controller method that returns a .xls file using sprint-test-mvc

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc, junit4

I'm using spring MVC in a project and now I have to implement a method on controller that exports some data in a .xls file.

I've read [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-document) and [some blogs](http://www.zabada.com/tutorials/excel-generation-with-spring-and-poi) about a way to implement this feature, but now I wanna know how to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching over the internet, I found a way to test this feature.
I figured out that I could test my AbstractJExcelView class implementation, based on [this link](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-maintenance/tags/release-1-1/test/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/document/ExcelTestSuite.java).

It basicaly creates the workbook created at the view, through the view's render method.